# The link should redirect to the log in page, later it should redirect to perticular page but not a defaut page

Tags: php, html

The link in the mail should redirect to the log in page. After that I should redirect to particular page but not a default page.

Ex: By default, after log-in to my web application will display the  **'HOME' page** . But if I click the link, which is in mail, should redirect me to the Log-in page of application and later it should redirect me to the **'create user' page**  (not to default one **HOME page**).

Could any one help that how can I achieve this.

Comment: is a session already created when you click on the mail link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be

1. On redirecting to Login page pass current URL as request/session (Whatever you choose) parameter to login page.
2. In the login page check if url parameter exists or not. If yes then again pass that to page containing loginAction.
3. In loginAction after login process check if url parameter exists or not. If exists then redirect to that url else redirect to default url.